# Is it possible to have a self-contained spring boot jar which can execute R scripts?

Tags: java, r, spring-boot

I have a spring boot + react application. The cool thing about spring boot is thus that it is able to run two different languages, namely Java and JavaScript anywhere without having to install many of the prerequisites like application or web servers.

My question is whether it is also possible to add a third language, namely R, such it is also completely contained in the JAR. And if yes is there any good framework and a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

There is a walkthrough of one such instance here: https://medium.com/graalvm/enhance-your-java-spring-application-with-r-data-science-b669a8c28bea

The demo application is found: https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-demos

In order to complete this, you must download GraalVM and add it to the path. You will also have to download any necessary dependencies for the particular project you are doing.

As far as packaging it all as a JAR, I would assume it is possible since everything is done within the project.

Comment: R might be a little bit tricky as it relies on the extensive ecosystem of modules that need to be installed somehow. Think maven pulling dependencies for R. These files normally go into the filesystem somewhere and used from there. In the example app you linked it's `Rscript -e "install.packages(\"ggplot2\")"`. I'm sure it's possible to package these in a jar, but I don't know enough to tell you how to import them then. Probably someone in the https://www.graalvm.org/slack-invitation can answer more thoroughly.